# Modify DOM in chrome:// scheme

Tags: google-chrome-extension

There is any way to modify the DOM in pages within the `chrome://` scheme?

`chrome://history/` for example.

Thanks and greetings.

Comment: There's a lame method only for personal use: [Can you access chrome:// pages from an extension?](//stackoverflow.com/a/19046796)

Comment: Thanks again, it works.